# probability of being dealt four of a kind in poker

Tags: probability

I have to resolve this exercise:

I have 52 cards. I get 5 cards. Calculate the probability I get a poker hand of four-of-a-kind.

well I applied  the formula ${52 \choose 5}=\frac{52!}{5!47!}$ to calculate every possible combination.but after here I don't know how can go ahead. Some help?

**Edit**

I made mistake.Now it's correct

Comment: $\binom{52}{5}=\frac{52!}{5!47!}$! What is a poker?

Comment: Yes, the term "poker" here is non-standard.

Comment: I mean for poker: 4 cards with identical value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wiki:Poker probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability), or better [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_rankings#Four_of_a_kind) here, you'll have the following:

> There are 624 possible hands including four of a kind; the probability of being dealt one in a five-card deal is $\frac {C_{13}^1 C_{4}^4 \cdot C_{12}^1 C_{4}^1} {C_{52}^5} = \frac {13 \cdot 1 \cdot 12 \cdot 4} {2{,}598{,}960} \approx 0.024\% $.

with $C_a^b=\binom{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Your formula is the total number of $5$ card hands.  How many choices of rank of the four are there?  How many choices for the other card?